# Setting the time of a System.DateTime object in PowerShell

Tags: date, powershell, time

I wish to set the System.DateTime object below with the time from $time:

```
$CurrentTime = (date)
$Time = "9:00"
```

How do I get the date from $CurrentTime, but with hours, minutes, seconds from $time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("09:00","hh:mm",$null)
```

Comment: I like the one liner.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$CurrentTime = [System.DateTime]::Parse((date).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"))
$Time = [System.Timespan]::Parse("9:00")
$Result = $CurrentTime.Add($Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Date -Year $CurrentTime.Year `
         -Month $CurrentTime.Month `
         -Day $CurrentTime.Day `
         -Hour $time.split(':')[0] `
         -Minute $time.split(':')[-1]
         -Second $time.split(':')[-1]
```

Comment: You can introduce them as well via the -Seconds parameter, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$CurrentTime = Get-Date -Hour "09" -Minute "00" -Second "00"
```